# Kindly explain the C program to me

Tags: c

I am reading the book [Windows System Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321657748). In the second chapter, there is a program `Cat.c`. It implements the `cat` command of linux. The code is http://pastebin.com/wwQFp599

Here is the part in which confuses me:

```
/*      iFirstFile is the argv [] index of the first input file. */
iFirstFile = Options (argc, argv, _T("s"), &dashS, NULL);

if (iFirstFile == argc) { /* No files in arg list. */
        CatFile (hStdIn, hStdOut);
        return 0;
}
```

As mentioned in the comment `iFirstFile` is the `argv []` index of the first input file.

It means if I try `cat -s abc.txt`, then `iFirstFile = 2`, but `argc == 3`.

I can't think in what circumstance `iFirstFile == argc` ? I can't understand the logic behind it. Can anyone explain me this part?

Comment: I'm not a windows programmer myself, but the answer may lie in how `Options` works - most likely taking the argument next to `_T("s")` regardless of the order which it was passed.

Comment: It probably just sets the index to the one-after-last if no file is found.

Comment: Not a Windows programmer neither but by the looks of it, when you call it like "cat" with no arguments, Options will return 1 and then CatFile will cat from stdin to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like it says in the comments, if there are no filenames in argv, then Options() returns argc. So this is the case where you want to cat stdin and not a file.

```
if (iFirstFile == argc) { /* No files in arg list. */
        CatFile (hStdIn, hStdOut);
        return 0;
}
```

For example "cat > x" reads from the stdin. So does "foo | cat | bar". In each of these cases Options() would return argc;

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program with:

```
cat
```

Then `argc == 1` and `iFirstFile == 1`.  Therefore the `if` statement condition will be true and it will run using `stdin` and `stdout`, allowing the use of pipes or interactive input, or output to the terminal window.